# Using SVM for subsets

Tags: machine-learning, svm, dataset, restrictions

Let's say I have a set of 20 data points. However, for certain unexplained reasons, I can only perform SVM on 4 of those data points at a time. Is there any way I can do SVM for each subset of 4 points for the 20-point dataset and then combine those vectors/planes/hyperplanes to get a more accurate result?

Comment: check out (sub)*bagging* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on exactly what you want to do,i will just give you some pointers.

If you want to combine predictions from multiple models, than that is called ensemble learning, in your case it would be probably called stacking. The simplest thing would be just to average predictions, or use majority voting.

Another way to approach this is that of you only have access to some points at the time you can build one model sequentially point by point. This is called online learning, and there are libraries for svm that can do it.

Last, is federated learning, where you build a single model while the data are never all at the same place, so that for example sensitive data do not have to be shared.

Maybe there are also other approaches